# Beautiful Soup Getting Text From "data-linkid"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, github4s

I am trying to get text form an attribute on a webpage and cannot seem to figure it out.

```
<span class="one-click-content css-1p89gle e1q3nk1v4" data-term="funny" data-linkid="nn1ov4">laughing out loud; laugh out loud: used as a response to something funny or as a follow-up to something said only as a joke.</span>
```

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_definition(word):
  string = word
  page = requests.get('https://www.dictionary.com/browse/' + string)
  src = page.content
  soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

  definition_string = ""
  definition_string = soup.find({"data-linkid": "nn1ov4"})

  return definition_string

print(get_definition("lol"))
```

I am trying to get "laughing out loud; laugh out loud: used as a response to something funny or as a follow-up to something said only as a joke." but instead I am getting "None"

Answer (score 1):

I have issues with using requests on this pc (work laptop) but in essence it is still the same.

If you only want the very first definition, then you can look for the first `<div>` with a `value=1` and get that text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

def get_definition(word):
  string = word
  page = urlopen('https://www.dictionary.com/browse/' + string)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

  definition_string = ""
  definition_string = soup.find('div', attrs={"value": "1"})
  string_text = definition_string.get_text()

  return string_text

print(get_definition("lol"))
```

The follow was returned:

```
laughing out loud; laugh out loud: used as a response to something funny or as a follow-up to something said only as a joke.
```

EDIT: Used OP's original code as much as I could instead of re-writting it.

Answer (score 0):

The definition is already available under meta-data

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_definition(word):
    page = requests.get('https://www.dictionary.com/browse/' + word)
    src = page.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
    mydivs = soup.findAll("meta", {"name": "description"})
    definition_string = mydivs[0]['content']
    return definition_string

print(get_definition("lol"))

Lol definition, laughing out loud; laugh out loud: used as a response to something funny or as a follow-up to something said only as a joke. See more.
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a tag name:

change

```
definition_string = soup.find({"data-linkid": "nn1ov4"})
```

to

```
definition_string = soup.find('a', {"data-linkid": "nn1ov4"})
```

then analyze and parse definition_string

Note: this works for 'cat' as you asked originally. If you search for 'lol' it does not find id 'nn1ov4' at all.

You can try:

```
definition_string = soup.find('span', {"data-linkid": "nn1ov4"})
```

but it will not work since there is no such param in HTML

Comment: The tag it is in isn't an "a" tag though so would I do a "span" tag instead? And would this return the text or would I still have to do something else?

Comment: right, but if you run it to search for 'cat', it will find id under 'a' tag, but if you run search for 'lol' it will not find it at all. Just try it and see

Comment: This solution still gives 'None'

Comment: I edited response, see my comment. If you are looking for some tag entry it must be there, otherwise soup will not show it

Comment: Ok well what I am trying to do is take in a user input, go get the deffinition for that, than output it. The only thing that stays they same for all of these diffrent deffinitions on diffrent webpages is this data-linkid. Do you have any suggestions of how I could do this for lets say not just 'cat' for 'lol' too?

Comment: @YusufBaktir change 'lol' to 'cat' (from original question) and see the result, with lol you have to specify different tag and different settings, you can take them from HTML code on the site

Comment: @LucianChauvin yes I do: first look at the page and find the text you want, then look at the HTML code and find the tag. Then make sure same tag with same settings works for all other user inputs. Then use soup and find tag with the settings you found optimal. Then parse the tag and get the phrase.